# How do I recover a dropped table from SQL Server Express 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Something disastrous happened to me.  I accidentally dropped my important table from SQL Server 2005 Express DB. Is there any way to recover that table with all records? Can DB Log file help? I have a backup until yesterday, and today's 6 hrs of transactions are lost.

Comment: if it's that important, then why is there no backup?

Comment: we have day end backups for this DB, but this happened in afternoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add this as an answer even though it's not a fix-all (unfortunately, you **need** to recover data that's not backed up).

### SCHEDULE REGULAR BACKUPS

SqlExpress doesn't have all the nice features the full version does (including backup plans), however, **[ExpressMaint](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=27)** is a great solution that you wire-up to your task scheduler via command-line execution. ***You can have it run as often as you want.*** It works great.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly why all RDBMS have log files, so you can recover from disasters like these.

For Sql Server 2005 [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191253(v=SQL.90).aspx) with a log file recovery process. And here is [another resource](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=132). The starting snippet from that article:

> A coworker calls you in a panic
>   because he accidentally deleted some
>   production data, and he wants you to
>   restore the lost records. ...

In this case, you are your own panicked co-worker.